# Как сделать Ajax запрос в базу при нажатии на обьект?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

Всем привет. Как сделать запрос в базу через Ајаx? У меня есть два div. Слева список всех записей из базы (но в урезанном виде 100 символов) А при нажатии я хочу чтобы в правом div появлялась вся запись.

Мой jsp файл

```
<div>
        <div>
            <div class="noteContextWindow" >
                <c:forEach items="${listNotes}" var="note">
                    <div class="notesList">
                        <a href="/notedata/${note.id}">${note.noteTitle}</a>
                        <br/>
                        <a class="contextInList">${note.noteContent}</a>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="noteContext">
            <a> Some text </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

текст из базы должен появляться где написано "Some text"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет,

как вариант, где `sendAjax` - id елемента в HTML:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#sendAjax").click(function(){
            send();
        });
    });

send: function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/test",
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        accepts: "application/json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        data : {"key":"value"},
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error : function(data){
            console.log("error: "+data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: А можно по подробней как я могу js использовать в jsp . Спасибо.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  <%@include file="/WEB-INF/js/handle.js"%>
 </script>

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не правильно выразился. Я имел ввиду как можно обработать само нажатие в jsp, чтобы запустился js код?

Comment: JSP - `<input type="button" id="sendAjax" value="Show">`
JS - 
 `$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#sendAjax").click(function(){
         send();
        });
    });`

Comment: А можно ли как-то обработать нажатие на запись в списке записей?

Comment: @Maksims можно, при генерации списка задавайте каждому елементу `id` и потом смотрите на ид елемента по которому кликнули